Breaker box 4" off floor
The breaker box is in the trailer home that we purchased.

Can we move box higher?
What is the best solution?
Can we leave it as is?


Pictures, please.

In particular, pictures that show the cables/wires coming out of the box and going into it, preferably ones that also show them going into the floor/walls/ceiling.  This will help answer whether or not you can move the box without rewiring.  Also, please tell us something about where you are.  At least country.  If in the US, please also include the state.  City might also be helpful if large enough to have its own electrical codes.

Usually you do not have extra wire/cable free to move it too much, if any.   If this is the way it was made by the travel trailer manufacturer, it should be done to code, so moving it should not be required by code, but your back/knees might like it.
